# PendingIntent fires when the alarm time is a multiple of 1 hour away from real time - Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am creating an Alarm clock app. I can set `PendingIntent`'s, cancel them, and receive them using my `BroadcastReceiver` when the time that I set using `AlarmManager` is reached. I discovered a recent problem however.

Previously, I have been able to set an alarm for any time in the future, and the BroadcastReceiver wouldn't "receive" the PendingIntent until that time was reached. I guess I never covered the scenario where the alarm to be set is exactly 1 or more (integers only) hours away. For example, the current time is 11:54, and I set an alarm for 12:54, or 1:54, 2:54, etc. When I do this, the BroadcastReceiver receives the PendingIntent and performs the actions that I told it to do.

Why does this happen? When I change the minute to something different, it doesn't happen, only if the minute is the same the app behaves as if I set the alarm for the current time.

This is how I set the alarms:

```
public void scheduleAlarm(Context aContext) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) aContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(aContext, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    String id = this.getId().replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");      // this.getId returns a string such as "alarm1". We only need the "1".

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(aContext, Integer.parseInt(id), intent, 0);

    // "this" in this context is the Alarm object. So you can get the hour and minute from the timepicker used to set the alarm
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, this.getHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, this.getMinute());

    long calendarTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarTime, alarmIntent);
}
```

Comment: Hard to believe. To check this, add logging just before you call `am.setExact()` which outputs the time value in `calendarTime` in a user readable format. Then check to see that the time is really the time you think it should be.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Is this still a problem? Any update?

Comment: Sorry just on a vacation, yes it doesnt happen anymore for some reason. I gave a fresh install of the app and it works fine. I cant reproduce the problem

Comment: OK, good that the problem is gone. Please either delete the question or answer your own question, so that the question is no longer in the "unanswered questions" list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the time that the alarm is set for, and confirmed that they were not the present time so they should not go off. After trying to set multiple alarms and seeing that the problem was still happening, I uninstalled the app from my phone, and gave it a fresh install. Everything worked fine afterwards and is still functioning correctly.